# Adding labels to ScatterChart in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have wrote this simple code to test things out for a more complicated one:

```
import sys

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import Reference, ScatterChart, Series
from openpyxl.chart.label import DataLabel, DataLabelList
from openpyxl.chart.marker import Marker
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
from openpyxl.drawing.colors import ColorChoice

wb = load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
for ws in wb:
    chart = ScatterChart(scatterStyle='smoothMarker')
    for x in range(2, 192):
        labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=x, max_row=x)
        xaxis = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=x, max_row=x)
        data = Reference(ws, min_col=3, max_col=3, min_row=x, max_row=x)
        s = Series(xaxis, data, title=ws['A' + str(x)].value)
        sp_color = ColorChoice(prstClr=(str(ws['A' + str(x)].value)))
        sp_sppr = GraphicalProperties(solidFill=sp_color)
        s.marker = Marker(symbol=('circle'), size=20, spPr=sp_sppr)
        s.marker.spPr.ln.noFill = True
        s.spPr.ln.noFill = True
        slabel = list()  #EDITED
        for x in labels.cells:  #EDITED
             slabel.append(ws[x].value)  #EDITED
        s.labels = DataLabelList(dLbl=slabel, dLblPos='bestFit')
        chart.series.append(s)
    chart.dataLabels = (DataLabelList(showLegendKey=True))
    ws.add_chart(chart, 'D1')
wb.save(sys.argv[1])
```

the file use as `sys.argv[1]` is like that (technically it's just the [color list](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.drawing.colors.html#openpyxl.drawing.colors.ColorChoice.prstClr) for prstClr of ColorChoice with x += 10 and y = x):

```
Color   x   y
beige   0   0
forestGreen 10  10
dkGoldenrod 20  20
lightPink   30  30
slateGrey   40  40
```

the line `s.labels = DataLabelList(dLbl=slabel, dLblPos='bestFit')` outputs the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'beige'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/chart/label.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.idx = idx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/nested.py", line 36, in __set__
    super(Nested, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 69, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'int'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv/test.py", line 37, in <module>
    s.labels = DataLabelList(dLbl=slabel, dLblPos='bestFit')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/chart/label.py", line 128, in __init__
    self.dLbl = dLbl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py", line 27, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py", line 27, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.chart.label.DataLabel'>
```

EDIT: I used a list as Charlie pointed it out without more success, this list should contains the same amount of items with the label names of each.
Either `slabel.append(ws[x].value)` or `slabel.append(x)` output the same error, what should that list contains?

> Versions:
>   -  openpyxl 2.4.8
>   -  python 3.6
>   -  macOS Siera 10.12.6

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`Sequence` is a descriptor used when writing classes you're using it incorrectly. You need to provide a Python sequence (list, tuple, etc.)

Comment: Edited the question with your remarks, this changed the errors. What should that list contains?

Comment: The exception makes this clear: a sequence of `DataLabel` objects. So, you probably need to change the code that creates `slabel` to create one of these instead, though I'm not sure that this what you really want to do. Unfortunately, the specification of charts is too complicated to discuss here. The mailing list would be a better place.