# can openpyxl amend chart data labels to values in selected cells?

Tags: openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet which contains values across three columns. A = Task, B = Date, and C = Team. I've written some simple code to build a excel scatter chart, place the values in column C on the y axis and values in column B on the x axis. However, I would like the chart data labels to be taken from column A. Is there and way of doing this?

At the moment I'm getting the data labels to be column B via using chart.dataLabels.showCatName = True ,which is useful but not what I need. I think it might be possible  by specifying the labels via the chart.dataLabels Parameter dLbl which stands for datalabellist. the source code for which is here http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.5/_modules/openpyxl/chart/label.html .

The most useful posts I found on this issue are here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/jB0pPVUtUsM, and here [Adding labels to ScatterChart in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591823/adding-labels-to-scatterchart-in-openpyxl)

At the moment the chart looks like this.

```
chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Team's Schedule"
chart.style = 7
chart.x_axis.title = 'Days'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Team'

xvalues = Reference(chart_sheet, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=20)
values = Reference(chart_sheet, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=20)
series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
chart.series.append(series)

s1 = chart.series[0]
s1.marker.symbol = "triangle"
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "FF0000" # Marker filling
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "FF0000" # Marker outline
s1.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True

chart.dataLabels = DataLabelList()
chart.dataLabels.showCatName = True

chart_sheet.add_chart(chart, "F2")
```